# Is there a risk of over-specification in an ARMA (and what are some other potential concerns)?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, error, arma

I'm trying to fit an ARMA to some data whilst controlling for seasonality using a Fourier series. Below are the plots of the ACF and PACF of the residuals and squared residuals respectively of an ARMA(8,4) process, that I believe fits well enough (but I'm willing to be told differently - I'm still learning how to eyeball data).

[image]
[image]

Additionally, in earlier modelling I had tried an ARMA(2,0). ACF and PACF plots are attached below.

[image]
[image]

My question is, at higher ARMA(p,q) orders, are there any risks I need to be aware of. For example, I know with regressions there is a risk of overspecification - is this a problem here (generally and in my case specifically), and are there any other potential concerns I should be aware of when undertaking this type of modelling?

Comment: Yes, a too complex model may fit well in sample but generalize poorly out of sample (where its good performance is actually needed). ARIMA is no exception.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Do you feel that an ARMA(8,4) is overly-complex (and, generally speaking, what are the highest ARMA orders to go to)? Moreover, does the ARMA(2,0) seem acceptable, or should I be concerned about that initial lag that is slightly outside the confidence interval?

Comment: It could depend on the application, but my experience is that (8,4) is pretty high (too high). See my answer for a couple more thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARMA(8,4) might be too complex. That is, it fits well in sample but may generalize poorly out of sample (where its good performance is actually needed).

ARMA(2,0) looks adequate except for autocorrelation at lag 1 in squared residuals. That calls for ARCH(1) structure in the conditional variance. So you could try AR(2)-ARCH(1).

Also pay attention to values of information criteria (AICc, AIC, BIC). This way you may get an indication which of the alternative models strikes the best balance between fit and model complexity.